# Why does JS cross out the event variable when I try to give it to an function as an argument?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I copied this code from w3schools. But the editor does cross out the word event.

The code worked. But I am not sure if I should change something because of the crossing out.

I want to make and application with this technique.

[Picture of the crossed out word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg2s3.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #div1, #div2 {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 35px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/02/01/06/chipmunk-5795916__340.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added a picture

Comment: Like notepad++. I used intellij for this. I added a picture were I show the problem.

Comment: @DreamBold If the IDE were rejecting inline event handlers, wouldn't it cross out the entire `ondrop`, not just the `event` argument?

Comment: This seems like a bug in intellij to me, you should report it to JetBrains.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. I tried to copy and run it in a browser.  When I tried to drop the picture, it refused to do it (crossed circle symbol)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: Updatet code: Uncaught TypeError: source is null

Comment: I did @DreamBold

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TwHcdp22 Here's the full code you can paste in HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better not use inline functions in your HTML code, use `addEventListener` for better code.

```js
let dragged = null;
 
const source = document.getElementById("draggable");
source.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
  // store a ref. on the dragged elem
  dragged = event.target;
});
 
const target = document.querySelectorAll(".dropzone");
target.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("dragover", (event) => {
    // prevent default to allow drop
    event.preventDefault();
  });
 
  item.addEventListener("drop", (event) => {
    // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
    event.preventDefault();
    // move dragged element to the selected drop target
    if (event.target.className === "dropzone") {
      dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
      event.target.appendChild(dragged);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  /* Prevent the user selecting text in the example */
  user-select: none;
}
 
#draggable {
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
 
.dropzone {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
  <img id="draggable" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/02/01/06/chipmunk-5795916__340.jpg" draggable="true" width="100" height="35">
</div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```